# Compare 2 fields in different rows of the same table

Tags: sql, oracle, select, compare

I want to return results from a join where the birth_date of two+ records are the same, but the person_id's are not equal. I am using Oracle. So if I got 4 results where rows 1 & 2 have the same birth_date and different person_id, those rows would be returned. Where rows 3 & 4 have the same birth_date and same person_id, those rows would not be returned. I get results, but I want to filter our results where the birth_date of rows are equal, but the person_id is <>.

```
  select t3.field1, t6.field2, t6.field3, t3.field4, t3.field5 
from table1 t1
    inner join table2 t2 on t1.@matching = t2.@matching
    inner join table3 t3 on t3.@matching = t1.@matching
    inner join table4 t4 on t4.@matching = t1.@matching
    inner join table5 t5 on t5.@matching = t4.@matching
    inner join table6 t6 on t6.@matching = t3.@matching
      where t1.@requirement = 'xxx' 
      and t2.@requirement = 'xxx' 
      and t2.@requirement is null 
      and t4.@requirement = 'xxx'
      and t5.@requirement = 'xxx' 
      and t1.@requirement ='xxx' 
      and t5.@requirement is null 
    order by t1.@field ASC;
```

Comment: Point of clarification. I've inner joined 6 tables to get my results. now I want to compare records in my joined table to each other. I know I can inner join the table I've created to itself. I guess I'm just wondering how the syntax would look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.birth_date, a.id, b.id
FROM   some_table a, some_table b
WHERE  a.birth_date = b.birth_date
AND    a.id < b.id
```

Note the usage of `<` instead of the intuitive `!=`. This is done to prevent the same combination returning in different orders (e.g. (1,2) and (2,1)).

Comment: I added the structure of my query. I would want to run that and get the results in the resulting table. Then run it again and compare the two. Every time I put in brackets, I get syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to group your data by person_id.. This will put all the records with the same person_id into 1 record

The query would look something like this

```
 SELECT a.birth_date, a.id, b.id
 FROM   some_table a, some_table b
 WHERE  a.birth_date = b.birth_date
 AND    a.id < b.id
 GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: I added the structure of my query. I would want to run that and get the results in the resulting table. Then run it again and compare the two. Every time I put in brackets, I get syntax errors.